# Can a 501(c)(7) have a class of members who can't vote in exchange for lower dues?

Tags: united-states, non-profit

Can a 501(c)(7) establish a class of membership that has no voting powers, in exchange for lower membership dues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the [statute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/501) and the [IRS guidance](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/other-non-profits/social-clubs) demand that membership dues be the major income source for the 501(c)(7) organization, but neither defines what "membership" is other than it must be limited.

My reading from this is yes, the club can have different levels of membership. However you'd want to get a proper legal advice from an attorney on the matter for an authoritative opinion.